# Вычисляемое поле в модели

Tags: mvc, yii, php

В таблице есть поле description, содержащие описание товара. В CGridView хочется выводить краткое описание товара, примерно 150 символов от полного. Его я сохраняю в `$short_description` следующим способом:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0, 150);   
}
```

К сожалению, данный метод не срабатывает. Какие ещё могут быть варианты? Вариант изменения данных в контроллере не рассматривается.

Класс модели наследуется от CActiveRecord.

Comment: хм... __construct срабатывает при инициализации класса, т.е. откуда там this->description, если класс пустой? Или он не пустой и там вбиты какие-то данные?

Использовать substr не рекомендую, резать русские символы будет ужас :) Используйте mb_substr, описание можно найти на php.net:

    mb_substr(str, start, end, encoding);

Comment: Данные вытаскиваются из базы данных посредством CActiveRecord .
Вариант с __construct изначально неверный, так как лазить в конструктор CActiveRecord была не самой моей лучшей идеей. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас в базе есть поле description, обрезая да 150 символов вы хотите получить поле shortdescription.
Порывшись в исходниках CActiveRecord далее CModel и далее CComponent смотрим на код волшебного метода __get()

```
public function __get($name)
    {
        $getter='get'.$name;
        if(method_exists($this,$getter))
            return $this->$getter();
        else if(strncasecmp($name,'on',2)===0 && method_exists($this,$name))
        {
            // duplicating getEventHandlers() here for performance
            $name=strtolower($name);
            if(!isset($this->_e[$name]))
                $this->_e[$name]=new CList;
            return $this->_e[$name];
        }
        else if(isset($this->_m[$name]))
            return $this->_m[$name];
        else if(is_array($this->_m))
        {
            foreach($this->_m as $object)
            {
                if($object->getEnabled() && (property_exists($object,$name) || $object->canGetProperty($name)))
                    return $object->$name;
            }
        }
        throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Property "{class}.{property}" is not defined.',
            array('{class}'=>get_class($this), '{property}'=>$name)));
    }
```

можно попробывать написать функцию getshortdescription

```
public function getshortdescription()
{
   return mb_substr($this->description,0,150)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите, какие параметры есть у класса, если, скажем, что-то вроде этого:

```
Class A {
    private description = '';

    public function __construct() {
        // вот сюда вы влезли
    }
...
}
```

И где-нибудь есть:

```
$record = new A();
```

То рекомендую просто расширить класс A:

```
Class B extends A {
    ...
}
```

Таким образом Вы получите доступ к this->description из класса B и сможете сделать все, что захотите, если, конечно, description не protected.

Comment: Но это теория пыха. Вообще, есть в классе CActiveRecord такие замечательные вещи, как EVENTS. Вам нужен onBeforeSave и не нужно придумывать велосипед :)

Comment: Но я ничего не сохраняю в БД. Это только промежуточная переменная, используемая для вывода данных.

Comment: Тогда делайте это при выводе модели, смотрите events.

Comment: public function onAfterConstruct()
 {
  $this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0,150);
 }
Не сработало.

Comment: А что возвращают аттрибуты? (attributes)
У меня есть подозрение, что атрибута short_description тут нет, а если есть, то он выводится раньше.
И вообще, сделайте логирование в файл $this->description и посмотрите, может и его нет.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в модель:

```
protected function afterFind(){
    $this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0, 150);  
    return $this;
}
```